# How to support outdoor gas pipe?

Tags: gas, pool, natural-gas

I'm planning on installing a natural gas pool heater. I want to have a 1-1/4" black iron pipe exit the house where it will run for about 5ft to the heater which will then be reduced to 3/4". I don't want the pipe to be in contact with the ground to prevent corrosion. I think it would also be easier to paint the underside of the pipe if it was elevated about 6 inches from the ground.

Being elevated like that does it make sense to place a permanent concrete block under the pipe somewhere halfway in-between the house and the heater? I want to protect the line and the equipment in case someone decides it's a good idea to stand on top of the pipe. Is there an an industry standard to something like this? Is the concrete block a good idea?

Comment: What is a _concert block_? I tried a Google Search, but it suggested that I search for _concrete block_.

Comment: Sorry, bad spelling. I meant to say concrete. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes much more sense - thanks! Though it's still misspelled in another place (which is why I was confused, I figured you didn't mistype it twice :) )

Comment: A [concrete block](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wb5HG.jpg), sometimes called cinder block, is poured concrete.

Answer (score 1):

If possible it is better to bury it to avoid exposure to the elements and damage from miscellaneous things. Having it above ground is no problem though as long as it is firmly supported. You don't say where you are, so without knowing the climate, there is no way to know how to support it.

One simple way to support it over soft ground is to drive a long metal rod into the ground, like a grounding rod, weld a split ring hanger to the rod, then fasten the pipe in the hanger.

Comment: I live in the Chicago land area. We do experience a lot of freeze-thaw over the winter.

Comment: @HarryGlinos In that case it is a good idea to make the rod or other support nice and deep, like 5 or 6 feet deep. Also, you might want to consider building a shed over the pipe and stuffing it with insulation. Otherwise the pipe will wick cold into the house. I am not joking here, having an uninsulated 5-foot pipe outdoors in the winter would be like leaving a window open all winter. One more reason for burying it.

Comment: How deep should I bury the pipe? If bury it, do I need to switch to galvanized pipe?

Comment: @HarryGlinos Maybe 4 feet or so. If it was me I would bury a conduit of 4" PVC pipe and then run the gas pipe thought the PVC. The advantage of this is that you don't have to worry about corrosion. Also, the PVC will provide some insulation. If there is any problem with the pipe, you can pull it out of the pipe with no need to dig it up.